# Can one use JDBC on an Android Application?

Tags: java, android, jdbc

I was thinking of making an Android Application, a Cook Book for example, that can be semi-online. Meaning the Application doesn't have to be online but it can be. An example would be that the users want to share recipes with other people on the network.

I'm going to use Java as the backend of the system, so I was thinking of using JDBC. Is that possible?

Comment: If you are thinking of JDBC over internet - don't: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15853367/jdbc-vs-web-service-for-android/15853566#15853566

Answer (score 0):

In android you can use sqlite database for your data storage or you can also use and Shared Preference it is are like java properties follow beloow link for quick reference of all...

for sqlite
http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html

for Shared Preference
http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidFileBasedPersistence/article.html

Comment: Isn't SQLite only data storage only for one device? Meaning you cannot share the data stored? Which is what I am planning to do to share.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use jdbc in Android.For apps requiring your data to be stored in some persistent storage,Android devices comes with in built SQLITE database where you can insert,update,delete and perform various operations on table created in it.

You can ask if you have any further queries.

Comment: Isn't SQLite only data storage only for one device? Meaning you cannot share the data stored? Which is what I am planning to do to share

Comment: For that purpose you have to use external database like mysql and use web services for interaction between mobile device and database..Then you can share your data with anyone who will use your app.